# mpl_finance module import error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have tried using `from matplotlib.finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl` but found that it is deprecated. Hence, I have installed `mpl_finance` and tried this:

```
from mpl_finance import quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl
```

But I got the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl'
```

I thought to check it:

```
dir(mpl_finance)
```

And found the following:

```
['Affine2D', 'Line2D', 'LineCollection', 'PolyCollection', 'Rectangle', 'TICKLEFT', 'TICKRIGHT', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_candlestick', '_check_input', '_plot_day_summary', 'absolute_import', 'candlestick2_ochl', 'candlestick2_ohlc', 'candlestick_ochl', 'candlestick_ohlc', 'division', 'index_bar', 'mcolors', 'np', 'plot_day_summary2_ochl', 'plot_day_summary2_ohlc', 'plot_day_summary_oclh', 'plot_day_summary_ohlc', 'print_function', 'unicode_literals', 'volume_overlay', 'volume_overlay2', 'volume_overlay3', 'xrange', 'zip']
```

Kindly, help me get rid of this issue. Please.

Comment: May be useful https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/8667

Answer (score 2):

Because yahoo has ceased to provide its historical quotes service, the `quotes_historical_yahoo_ochl` function stopped working. [It was hence removed](https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance/pull/9) from the `mpl_finance` code completely.

Comment: So it there no way I can achieve what I wanted?

Comment: You will need to find another source for the data you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you sir... I will try it out.